# Ubuntu 16: Configuring a (trunk) interface w/o IP address

Tags: networking, 16.04

I intend to use one of my Ubuntu 16 interfaces as a trunk, so I don't need any IP configuration on that interface (it'll all be on VLAN-bound subinterfaces). How do I configure it w/o an IP address? At present it has an IP address automatically allocated to it by the NFVI (Openstack) during VM deployment, and if I try hashing it out in /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg I get this:

```
root@client:/etc/network/interfaces.d# service networking restart
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@client:/etc/network/interfaces.d#
```

Unhashing it there clears the issue. Is there a "no ip address" of some kind?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Does not "configure" an address... but it will receive an APIPA address

in my /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth2.nmconnection:
[connection]
id=eth2
uuid=7f734eee2-365a-9ca1-14fbc22246f1
type=ethernet
.
.
.
[ethernet]
duplex=full
mac-address=31:B0:0B:CA:FE:13
mac-address=blacklist=
speed=100

[ipv4]
dns-search=
**method=link-local**

[ipv6]
.
method=disabled

Comment: Thank you - is there a CLI equivalent of it though, which I can put into my /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg ?

Comment: At the moment I have "iface ens5 inet static", so apparently IP config should follow. Perhaps there's a keyword instead of "static" to tell it no IP config is needed, hence none follows? I wouldn't like to use "dhcp" as it still implies IP assignment albeit automatic.

Comment: I dont know about that method... but my /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth2.nmconnection designates it as the above edited answer...

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately my VM has no system-connections under /etc/NetworkManager (it has only dispatcher.d/ with hook-network-manager in it). Worth noting that everything keeps working fine even when I remove "ip address" line under my interface in /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg , it's just that error message during "service networking restart" that I'd ideally like to get rid of.

Comment: Apparently assigning link-local via CLI clears the error too - but only when assigning IPv6 link-local with "iface ens5 inet6 auto". An attempt to assign IPv4 link-local with "iface ens5 inet auto" still returns the error but I'm fine with IPv6 link-local anyway. It'd still have been nice to let an interface be brought up w/o any IPv4/IPv6 address whatsoever though, e.g. exactly for use as trunk. Thanks for the hint meanwhile )

Comment: If you want the interface to be "up" it would have to, at least, have a link-local address. i don't think there was a way around that... it gets assigned automatically if no IP gets established. I use it for a similar reason to what you described

Comment: Yes seems like it's Linux's vision of networking as if an interface is not supposed to be brought up w/o an IP address )  In fact it looks like an interface w/o a valid IP config whatsoever still gets assigned an IPv6 link local by default anyway.